# Transformation in SVGs

Tags: css, svg, transform

I have an SVG image I want to apply CSS transform to... it worked however it misbehaves a lot.. I want the path of the SVG to rotate around a fixed point just like the second hand in the clock.. here is what I have achieved so far... How can I possibly rotate this hand(svg path or group) round a fixed point.. see my code snippet for further info. THANKS IN ADVANCE.

```css
    html{
     min-height: 100%;
    }
   body{
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 625px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center; 
    align-content: center;
    align-items: center;

   }
   .fil3 {
       animation: rotate 5s infinite;
             transition: all 0.5s;
             transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.1, 2.7, 0.58, 1);
    transform-origin: center;
   }
   @keyframes rotate {
     100% {
       transform: rotate(360deg);
     }
   }
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd">
  <!-- Creator: CorelDRAW X7 -->
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xml:space="preserve" width="300px" height="500px" version="1.0" style="shape-rendering:geometricPrecision; text-rendering:geometricPrecision; image-rendering:optimizeQuality; fill-rule:evenodd; clip-rule:evenodd"
  viewBox="-950 0 2111 828"
   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
   <defs>
    <style type="text/css">
     <![CDATA[
      .fil2 {fill:#848688}
      .fil4 {fill:#F8A25F}
      .fil1 {fill:#848688;fill-rule:nonzero}
      .fil3 {fill:#F8A25F;fill-rule:nonzero;}
      .fil0 {fill:#A0CD47;fill-rule:nonzero}
     ]]>
    </style>
   </defs>
   <g id="Layer_x0020_1">
    <metadata id="CorelCorpID_0Corel-Layer"/>
    <path class="fil0" d="M347 478l0 154 0 146c0,38 24,45 37,45 12,0 37,-7 37,-45l0 -149 0 -148 0 -149c0,-38 -25,-45 -37,-45 -13,0 -37,7 -37,45l0 146z"/>
    <path class="fil1" d="M479 266l-109 110 -103 103c-27,27 -14,49 -5,58 9,9 31,22 58,-5l105 -106 105 -105 236 -237c27,-27 14,-49 5,-58 -8,-9 -31,-22 -58,5l-234 235z"/>
    <circle class="fil2" cx="384" cy="414" r="82"/>
    <g>
    <path class="fil3" d="M119 155l105 114 242 262c25,28 39,25 44,20 4,-4 9,-17 -17,-45l-244 -265 -100 -109 -101 -109c-26,-28 -40,-24 -44,-20 -5,4 -10,17 16,45l99 107z"/>
    </g>
    <circle class="fil4" cx="384" cy="414" r="37"/>
   </g>
  </svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `transform-orgin` you should specify the centre of the clock.  The coordinates for that can be directly read from the `cx` and `cy` coordinates of the orange circle at the centre of the clock face.

```
transform-origin: 384px 414px;
```

Your demo updated with that change:

```css
html{
     min-height: 100%;
    }
   body{
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 625px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center; 
    align-content: center;
    align-items: center;

   }
   .fil3 {
       animation: rotate 5s infinite;
             transition: all 0.5s;
             transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.1, 2.7, 0.58, 1);
    transform-origin: 384px 414px;
   }
   @keyframes rotate {
     100% {
       transform: rotate(360deg);
     }
   }
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd">
  <!-- Creator: CorelDRAW X7 -->
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xml:space="preserve" width="300px" height="500px" version="1.0" style="shape-rendering:geometricPrecision; text-rendering:geometricPrecision; image-rendering:optimizeQuality; fill-rule:evenodd; clip-rule:evenodd"
  viewBox="-950 0 2111 828"
   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
   <defs>
    <style type="text/css">
     <![CDATA[
      .fil2 {fill:#848688}
      .fil4 {fill:#F8A25F}
      .fil1 {fill:#848688;fill-rule:nonzero}
      .fil3 {fill:#F8A25F;fill-rule:nonzero;}
      .fil0 {fill:#A0CD47;fill-rule:nonzero}
     ]]>
    </style>
   </defs>
   <g id="Layer_x0020_1">
    <metadata id="CorelCorpID_0Corel-Layer"/>
    <path class="fil0" d="M347 478l0 154 0 146c0,38 24,45 37,45 12,0 37,-7 37,-45l0 -149 0 -148 0 -149c0,-38 -25,-45 -37,-45 -13,0 -37,7 -37,45l0 146z"/>
    <path class="fil1" d="M479 266l-109 110 -103 103c-27,27 -14,49 -5,58 9,9 31,22 58,-5l105 -106 105 -105 236 -237c27,-27 14,-49 5,-58 -8,-9 -31,-22 -58,5l-234 235z"/>
    <circle class="fil2" cx="384" cy="414" r="82"/>
    <g>
    <path class="fil3" d="M119 155l105 114 242 262c25,28 39,25 44,20 4,-4 9,-17 -17,-45l-244 -265 -100 -109 -101 -109c-26,-28 -40,-24 -44,-20 -5,4 -10,17 16,45l99 107z"/>
    </g>
    <circle class="fil4" cx="384" cy="414" r="37"/>
   </g>
  </svg>
```

Answer (score 2):

In SVG world everything is relative to the axis origin (even transformations), it is not misbehaving. I changed the animation and deleted the transition properties as they are not needed. Please try the following:

```css
    html{
     min-height: 100%;
    }
   body{
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 625px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center; 
    align-content: center;
    align-items: center;

   }
   .fil3 {
    transform: translate(380px, 410px) rotate(0deg);
       animation: rotate 5s infinite;
   }
   @keyframes rotate {
     100% {
       transform: translate(380px, 410px) rotate(360deg);
     }
   }
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd">
  <!-- Creator: CorelDRAW X7 -->
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xml:space="preserve" width="300px" height="500px" version="1.0" style="shape-rendering:geometricPrecision; text-rendering:geometricPrecision; image-rendering:optimizeQuality; fill-rule:evenodd; clip-rule:evenodd"
  viewBox="-950 0 2111 828"
   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
   <defs>
    <style type="text/css">
     <![CDATA[
      .fil2 {fill:#848688}
      .fil4 {fill:#F8A25F}
      .fil1 {fill:#848688;fill-rule:nonzero}
      .fil3 {fill:#F8A25F;fill-rule:nonzero;}
      .fil0 {fill:#A0CD47;fill-rule:nonzero}
     ]]>
    </style>
   </defs>
   <g id="Layer_x0020_1">
    <metadata id="CorelCorpID_0Corel-Layer"/>
    <path class="fil0" d="M347 478l0 154 0 146c0,38 24,45 37,45 12,0 37,-7 37,-45l0 -149 0 -148 0 -149c0,-38 -25,-45 -37,-45 -13,0 -37,7 -37,45l0 146z"/>
    <path class="fil1" d="M479 266l-109 110 -103 103c-27,27 -14,49 -5,58 9,9 31,22 58,-5l105 -106 105 -105 236 -237c27,-27 14,-49 5,-58 -8,-9 -31,-22 -58,5l-234 235z"/>
    <circle class="fil2" cx="384" cy="414" r="82"/>
    <g>
    <path class="fil3" d="M119 155l105 114 242 262c25,28 39,25 44,20 4,-4 9,-17 -17,-45l-244 -265 -100 -109 -101 -109c-26,-28 -40,-24 -44,-20 -5,4 -10,17 16,45l99 107z"/>
    </g>
    <circle class="fil4" cx="384" cy="414" r="37"/>
   </g>
  </svg>
```